# Helm encrypt decrypt AES -- openssl parameters

Tags: kubernetes, encryption, openssl, kubernetes-helm

There is a function in helm template

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#encryptaes

```
encryptAES "secretkey" "plaintext"
# result below
```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#decryptaes

```
"30tEfhuJSVRhpG97XCuWgz2okj7L8vQ1s6V9zVUPeDQ=" | decryptAES "secretkey"
# result 'plaintext'
```

**What openssl parameters I need to use to generate string that can be decrypted with helm with its AES implementation?**

---

There is a implementation for doing thing that I want but in not so simple as pipe to openssl some b64 string and get right result

Because in another way I need to say developers to install kubectl/helm and play with their secrets as they can

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question but this maybe?
openssl rsa -aes128 -in /tmp/tls.key -passout pass:somepassword -out /tmp/encrypted_tls.key

Comment: @adam-sranko 
I try such parameters 
```
printf plaintext | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -A -a -nosalt -k secretkey 
#output
nCY6OdEbucbTWTr/O1YAZg==
```
and I think there is some parameters which give the same result for same input

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party here.

I had a similar question myself: I wanted to automate tasks outside of helm and feed secure data from those tasks to helm.

I worked out how to code encryptAES in python3. Not openssl but python is widely available. Gist here: https://gist.github.com/andydarlow/1b05c0813f759d07b7806c86983809b2

Hope it helps somebody.

For the people who may have issues with the link above, the code is:

```py
    # Recreation of Helm's encryptAES function in python
    # Requires pycryptodome to function. see https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
    #
    # use in your code to create an ecrypted value for a field then you can decrypt with helm's secret | decrypt Password
    #
    # Found this useful when integrating with other components and you need the encrypt the password (e.g. create a DB then encrypt
    # the password for that auto created database for use in Helm.
    # (forgive my Python - i'm no python expert - enjoy :) )
    
    import base64
    from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
    import random
    from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad
    
    # SPRIG uses only 32 characters from the password!
    # If the password is too small, it will be padded with zero bytes
    PASSWORD_LENGTH = 32
    
    
    def to_length(byte_array, required_length):
        """
        fix the size of byte array to 'required length. It will pad with the byte 0 if there aren't enough
        characters in byte_array OR truncate if there are too many character in the byte array
        :param byte_array: fix this byte_array to required_length in length
        :param required_length: how many characters must be found in the resulting array
        :return: a copy of byte_array, truncated to required_length bytes or padded if need be
        """
        return (byte_array[:required_length] +
                bytes(max((required_length - len(byte_array), 0))))
    
    
    def encryptAES(plaintext, password):
        """
        helm's encryptAES written in python3
        (see https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#cryptographic-and-security-functions)
        this is a copy of the sprig (the util Helm uses) code found here: https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/crypto.go
        :param plaintext: text to encrypt
        :param password: the password used to encrypt the data with
        :return: a base64 encrypted version of plaintext
        """
        key = to_length(bytes(password, 'utf-8'),PASSWORD_LENGTH)  # fixed sized, 0 padded password
        iv = random.randbytes(AES.block_size)  # fixed sized IV to make simple decoding in SPRIG.
        encrypted = (AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
                        .encrypt(pad(bytes(plaintext, 'utf-8'), AES.block_size)))
        # sprig (helm) stores the IV (fixed sized) and encrypted together as a self-contained string for decryption
        return base64.b64encode(iv + encrypted)
```

Comment: In my case I wrote [python script](https://gist.github.com/BoogerMan2103/3589f30d026e4fe8c48e59c39ef25713) that calls openssl with some parameters and key-string
That need to be able to run script in any environment with python(with pyyaml)+openssl(itself).
Encrypted files put into repo, ci decrypt file with secret-key, and includes result into helm values